# Using Web Api 2 and Angular, specify that no data is returned? (No error either)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

Let's say my **API** returns a list of dates a product was viewed for simplicity. Some of the products were never viewed, and an empty list will be returned. When this happens, I want to show:

> This product hasn't been viewed yet!

and hide the table with product view dates. I do this in the controller returning `IHttpActionResult`:

```
if (itemViewedDto.Count > 0)
{
     return Ok(itemViewedDto);
}
else
{
    return Ok(new {message = "No data"}); 
}
```

On the client I do (itemViewed is just the http response payload):

```
    $scope.dataExists = function(){
        if($scope.itemViewed.hasOwnProperty(message)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And then show response accordingly using ng-if or whatever to see if there was a response or not?

Is there anything wrong with this? Is this an accepted pattern? If not, what's a better way to do it? I am asking conceptually, not for this particular situation.

Currently its work for me, just I'm curious to know if it's wrong.

Comment: I suppose I could simply check for whether or not the response is empty, but someone told me to make the message property. Essentially I am wondering if that part is wrong.

Comment: I find this ugly. Why not just return always the same thing: an itemViewDto. If the UI layer wants to display a different message and hide a table when the list is empty, it just has to test if the list is empty. See https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsgfgqfgqdgsdfqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsf for example, which lists all the github repositories named `dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsgfgqfgqdgsdfqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of proper HTTP Status Codes and return a 204 No Content. WebApi doesn't provide a "NoContent" result, but you can provide one very easily with a "NoContentResult" class. This way you can stick with IHttpActionResults and not fall back to HttpResponseMessages.

```
public class NoContentResult : OkResult
{
    public NoContentResult(ApiController controller) : base(controller) { }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken).Result;
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

And now to use it and your status code will be set with an empty body:

```
if (itemViewedDto.Count > 0)
{
    return Ok(itemViewedDto);
}
else
{
    return new NoContentResult(this);
}
```

If you are using a base class for all your controllers, you can add this to your base class and then it will feel just like an Ok response.

```
public abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a No Content response.
    /// </summary>
    protected NoContentResult NoContent()
    {
        return new NoContentResult(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
if (itemViewedDto.Count > 0)
{
    return Ok(itemViewedDto);
}
else
{
    return NoContent();
}
```

Now in your JavaScript you can respond to different status codes rather than parsing the body.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would avoid returning two different types of responses on a successful API call. It looks smelly, and serves absolutely no purpose. Just return a list, even if it is an empty list. On the Angular side just check if the array is empty or not and do your display logic based on that.